# Hazelcast management center queue statistic

Tags: hazelcast

I use hazelcast IMDG free edition and hazelcast management center 4.2020.8
I ask you if into the queue view is possible to reset the statistics of the "max-age"/"min-age"/"average age".
Actually the only mode that I find is to destroy and recreate the queue.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to reset the statistics of the queue either from Management Center or using Hazelcast's Java API. That might be an interesting addition though. I would suggest you to create a new issue for this in [Hazelcast GitHub repository](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/new?labels=Type%3A+Enhancement&template=feature_request.md) and tag it with `Team: Management Center`.

Comment: I open issue Hazelcast IMDG -- Hazelcast Management Center -- Queue statistic #17751; 
I try to tag the team but not work.

Comment: Thanks! I already tagged it and let our product manager know about it so that he can prioritize it accordingly.